# how to expand content for a TD to cover 100% of its height (IE)

Tags: html, css

I have a table with one TR and two TDs, one of the TDs has more content (i mean with content: other sub tables) than the other one, this results the following:

the TD with the little content stay shrinked (its content stay as is, not expanded) and this happens in case of IE only, firefox and google chrome are fine, both of FF and chrome do expand the smaller TD content to fill 100% of that TD's height, my question is how to expand the content of the smaller TD to fill 100% of its height ?

p.s. I tried height: 100%; on the smaller TD but didn't work ...and this is a dynamic code, means that both TDs are changable with their content according to some criteria ...

look at both screenshots:
[image]

[image]

thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Put a `<div>` inside the TD cell where you specify the exact height you want it to be.

Comment: Hi webdestroya, I put the DIV in the right place and give it a height of 100% but did not work :( .. it only works with fixed heights (200px ...) and that does not get it working the right way.